# Dont know what hose this is and why its leaking when not running

Tags: leak, dishwasher

I don't know what hose is leaking. I tried replacing the metal thing you tighten on it at the end but that didn't work. How do I know what hose it is on my ge dishwasher its the black hose sorry for not knowing names just a single mom trying to fix it on the cheap side thank you for your help.[image]

Comment: Can you circle the area that is leaking, and post some more photos of the area from different angles?

Comment: It can be helpful to take some toilet paper and wrap it around various points of a  hose to determine where it's leaking.  Could be at the joint, could be somewhere further up.